# How do I make two user variable's equal the same answer in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am having a user input a string for variable "input" and then running an if statement which works like:
.

```
If input = "pick up silver" Then

ElseIf input = "grab silver" Then

invt(i) = worth.Silver
```

However, I have a large array of different metals, is there a way to condense both if's onto one line in order to preserve space, I have tried

```
If input = "pick up silver" OR "grab silver" Then
invt (i) = worth.silver
```

However, this does not work as it attempt's to put both IF's as a boolean.

The entire code is here https://mega.nz/#!fspXHQKD!naMZCAPx3c8fkYtYh9haWSryEJciLpjqwCxkXRU-dVg

Apologies for poor formatting and any errors I may have made, this is one of my first attempts at coding and if I could get help with this silver error, it would help a lot throughout the entire procedure.

Also, if I have left out any important information, please ask, I am new to this website...

Answer (score 0):

Just flip it around: define the accepted values in an array then check if that arrays includes your `input:

```
Dim Metals() As String = { "pick up silver", "grab silver" }

If Metals.Contains(input) Then
    invt(i) = worth.Silver
End If
```

Or you can also consider a `Select` statement (called "switch" in other languages):

```
Select Case Input
    Case "pick up silver"
    Case "grab silver"
        ' Do something

    Case "gold"
    Case "rose gold"
        ' Do something else

    Case Else

End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select case structure.

```
Select Case input
  Case "pick up silver", "grab silver"
    invt(i) = worth.Silver
  Case "gold", "whatever gold"
    invt(i) = worth.Gold
  Case Else
    Debug.WriteLine("Not recognized")
End Select
```

If you need to use the if sentence necessarily then use

```
If input = "pick up silver" OR input = "grab silver" Then
 invt (i) = worth.silver
End If
```